# How can I list user and user's roles in weblogic by wlst?

Tags: java, weblogic, wlst

Does anyone know how to list all the weblogic users and user's roles list in java ( wlst )?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

User list :

```
from weblogic.management.security.authentication import UserReaderMBean
from weblogic.management.security.authentication import GroupReaderMBean
realm=cmo.getSecurityConfiguration().getDefaultRealm()
atns = realm.getAuthenticationProviders()
for i in atns:
    if isinstance(i,UserReaderMBean):
        userReader = i
        cursor = i.listUsers("*",0)
        print 'Users in realm '+realm.getName()+' are: '
        while userReader.haveCurrent(cursor):
            print userReader.getCurrentName(cursor)
            userReader.advance(cursor)
        userReader.close(cursor)
for i in atns:
    if isinstance(i,GroupReaderMBean):
        groupReader = i
        cursor = i.listGroups("*",0)
        print 'Groups in realm are: '
        while groupReader.haveCurrent(cursor):
            print groupReader.getCurrentName(cursor)
            groupReader.advance(cursor)
        groupReader.close(cursor)
```

Role list :

```
rm=cmo.getSecurityConfiguration().getDefaultRealm().lookupRoleMapper("XACMLRoleMapper")
print rm.getProviderClassName()
print rm.getName()

cursor = rm.listAllRoles(1000)
print cursor

userReader = rm 
while userReader.haveCurrent(cursor):
    usrrd = userReader.getCurrentProperties(cursor)
    print usrrd.get('RoleName') 
    #print usrrd
    print "\t",usrrd.get('Expression')

    userReader.advance(cursor)
userReader.close(cursor)
```

Comment: thank you so much your answer. But I want both of them. For example; 
 Emmanuel Collin-administrator